# Beacon Ranging in Background on iOS

Tags: ios, core-location, ibeacon

I understand the difference between monitoring and ranging, and I understand the limitation of iOS in that beacon ranging can only happen in the foreground or in the background when entering and exiting regions as explained here (http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/11/13/ibeacon-monitoring-in-the-background-and-foreground.html). But I'm trying to figure out how to solve a common scenario.

If I had a bunch of beacons installed in a department store, how am I supposed to detect when a person moves within range of those beacons? With the way it currently works, the app will get an event when the user enters the store (`didEnterRegion`) because the collection of all beacons acts as one big region. But there's no way to know that a user is moving between different sections of the store unless the beacons are placed far enough for the user to exit and enter the region again which is probably not practical.

The reason I want to range for beacons in the background is that I might need to know that a user is at a specific section/product in the store to display specific offers/information (through a notification) for that section without needing the user to have the app open.

This seems to me like a very common scenario for malls and museums, etc... I'm wondering how other developers solved this or whether there's another way of achieving what I want.

I didn't include code snippets here because the issue is not with the code, it's just a conceptual issue. If any clarification or code is needed I can add that too.

Thanks

Comment: is there any answers that solves your question ? or could you solve it ?

Answer (score 7):

The biggest part of the answer is the technique documented by my colleague @csexton in another answer to this question.

In order to solve the second problem of only getting 10 seconds of ranging time after a transition, you can request additional time to keep ranging.  iOS allows you to continue ranging in the background for up to 180 seconds.  This requires no background modes and no special permission from the AppStore.

Note:  **You can also get unlimited background ranging time** if you request a special background mode and do some other setup steps as described in [my blog post here](http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2023/02/10/forever-ranging).

Here's how you set that up:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    if (_inBackground) {
        [self extendBackgroundRunningTime];
    }
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self logString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"applicationDidEnterBackground"]];
    [self extendBackgroundRunningTime];
    _inBackground = YES;
}


- (void)extendBackgroundRunningTime {
    if (_backgroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
        // if we are in here, that means the background task is already running.
        // don't restart it.
        return;
    }
    NSLog(@"Attempting to extend background running time");
    
    __block Boolean self_terminate = YES;
    
    _backgroundTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"DummyTask" expirationHandler:^{
        NSLog(@"Background task expired by iOS");
        if (self_terminate) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:_backgroundTask];
            _backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        }
    }];
    
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSLog(@"Background task started");
        
        while (true) {
            NSLog(@"background time remaining: %8.2f", [UIApplication sharedApplication].backgroundTimeRemaining);
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
        }
        
    });
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self logString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"applicationDidBecomeActive"]];
    _inBackground = NO;
}
```

Getting 180 seconds to range in the background is no silver bullet, but it solves many use cases that 10 seconds does not.

You can read a full writeup on how this works, along with test results here:  https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/ibeacon-background-demo/tree/background-task

Comment: Does this work if the user has manually terminated the app in the multitasker?

Comment: Terminating the app in the multiasker will stop ranging immediately.  However on iOS 7.1+, if a monitored beacon is detected, it will launch the app in the background and start the process all over again.  On iOS 7.0, killing the app in the multitasker will stop it for good until the user launches it again manually.

Comment: Makes sense. So if the user terminates the app while standing in range of the beacon, will it relaunch immediately? Or do they need to exit and re-enter to receive the region entry callback?

Comment: Do you have any experience with apps implementing "Long Running Tasks" in order to continue ranging in the background for longer than 180s?  Are they even feasible?  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html seems to indicate that they are (Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories), but I don't know if that applies to ranging for beacons.

Comment: It is the location background modes that applies to ranging.  You can request this, and then range as long as you want, but you will need to convince app store reviewers that this is legitimate -- e.g. that you have a background navigation app.  The "external accessories" clause refers to connecting with bluetooth devices like the Apple Watch -- I don't think it applies to CoreLocation.

Comment: you can range in the background using this techie: https://community.estimote.com/hc/en-us/articles/203914068-Is-it-possible-to-use-beacon-ranging-in-the-background-

Answer (score 3):

I would probably model this by breaking up the store into multiple regions. How they would be modeled would be based on the use-cases you have for when a notification is triggered.

I would do this by giving them all the same UUID, but different Major values. Then use the minor values to differentiate between stores. This way as they move from region the app will register a `didEnter` event.

You can have about 20 regions registered, so I would be careful when grouping beacons together.

For Example:

- UUID:`754A5D70-C59E-4E39-AA56-ED646903EF5B` Major:`1` → Entrance
- UUID:`754A5D70-C59E-4E39-AA56-ED646903EF5B` Major:`2` → Cash Registers
- UUID:`754A5D70-C59E-4E39-AA56-ED646903EF5B` Major:`3` → Clothing
- UUID:`754A5D70-C59E-4E39-AA56-ED646903EF5B` Major:`4` → Housewares
- ...

Then as the users of the app move through the store you can trigger actions upon crossing the boundaries of the regions.

This way you can:

1. Get the enter and exit callback
2. Start ranging to find out the Minor values (which could be per store or unique for each beacon)
3. Send the local notification

Comment: I thought about that. The issue is that breaking the beacons into multiple regions might not be granular enough. In some cases, I might need to display an offer or information in relation to a specific single beacon. And iOS has a global limit of 20 regions across ALL apps as I understand, so it's not practical.

Comment: I think you can work around that, see my edits -- tried to address this.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. Another issue is that once I get the region entry callback, I can only range beacons for around 10 seconds, after that, the app goes back to the background. So if we had a large clothing section, we would only range around the edge of the region but can't range inside the region in case I need to display a notification regarding a specific beacon. Unless the user opens the app.

Comment: @csexton is absolutely right about this technique.  For information on extending ranging time, see the answer I have provided.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is make sure all of your beacons have the same UUID. Then, register a single CLBeaconRegion for monitoring that specifies ONLY that UUID. Do not include a major or minor value. This will cause `didEnterRegion:` to be called when ANY beacon matching that UUID is entered (major and minor values are wildcarded). However, the CLBeaconRegion returned here will only have the UUID, and no major/minor, just like how you registered it so you don't know exactly which beacon fired. To figure out exactly which beacon your device is seeing, when `didEnterRegion:` is called, tell the location manager to `startRangingBeaconsInRegion:` with the entered region. The location manager will then call back to you with `didRangeBeacons:` passing an array of CLBeacons. These CLBeacons will know their major and minor values, from which you can determine exactly which part of the store the user is in (because you know where the beacon with that major/minor is deployed). This can all be done while the app is in the background.

This way you are only registering a single CLBeaconRegion, yet you can still interact with any beacon matching the UUID that you've registered with.

I've used this method to do successful deployments of 80+ beacons in one area, which all successfully fired in the foreground and background. You do not need the user to open the app to accomplish this.

Comment: This is exactly what I do now. But this doesn't allow you to keep ranging for beacons once you're INSIDE the region. So if a user enters the region I can range right away to see what beacon is firing, but if they move around inside the region I can't keep ranging to see what beacon they're moving to.

Comment: Once you enter the region and call startRangingBeaconsInRegion on that region, the location manager will keep ranging any beacons it sees with that UUID until didExitRegion is called, at which point you should call stopRangingBeaconsInRegion. Is that not what you're experiencing?

Comment: Strange. No that's not what I'm experiencing. For me, once I get `didEnterRegion`, I call `startRangingBeaconsInRegion` and that will give me regular callbacks (one per second) for up to around 10 seconds. Nothing after that.

Comment: Do you have any specific background modes enabled? Or did you configure anything specifically to allow ranging in the background to continue?

Comment: Location updates background mode is required for this to work (on iOS 8 at least)

Comment: I've added Location updates background mode but I'm still seeing the 10 second limit. Are you calling `startUpdatingLocation` for the sake of keeping the app running in the background?

Comment: I agree you still have a 10 second limit even if you set background modes.  You can extend this to 180 seconds (see my answer that shows how to do this.)  Getting more time than that probably works only if you have an app that implements "Long Running Tasks" in the background, which Apple severely restricts per this document:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html