# iOS monitoring/ranging beacons in background consumes a lot of battery

Tags: ios, background, ibeacon

In iOS we implemented the monitoring and ranging of ibeacons in the background. When the device enters a region, we start ranging for ibeacons in the background. When the device exits a region we stop ranging for ibeacons in the background.

This works really well when we issue the following statement when starting the app:
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

and we can keep ranging the beacons in the background for the whole time that we are within the region.

When we do not issue this statement, the ranging of iBeacons in the background stops after a couple of seconds after starting it. This is not good enough for our application since we need to keep ranging the beacons while we are within a region.
What we also see it that monitoring and ranging for beacons in the background in this way takes a lot of battery power.

Has anyone experience with this? Is the battery consumption in the background caused by the startUpdatingLocation() (which also generates callbacks for didUpdateLocations() with latitude and longitude which we do not need)? Is there another way to avoid the ranging for beacons to be stopped after a couple of seconds in the background?

I saw this other entry [Beacon Ranging in Background on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368403/beacon-ranging-in-background-on-ios) but only ranging for 180 seconds is also not what we really want. The entry says:
In order to solve the second problem of only getting 10 seconds of ranging time after a transition, you can request additional time to keep ranging. iOS allows you to continue ranging in the background for up to 180 seconds. This requires no background modes and no special permission from the AppStore.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a blog post about the various options you have here:

http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/11/13/extending-background-ranging-on-ios.html

The basic options are:

- Use location background mode to range constantly in the background -- this is essentially the same technique as setting `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` you mention.   The disadvantage is that you must convince Apple you have a location app to get approval for the AppStore.
- Request extra background running time.  Details are mentioned in the blog post link, but this only gets you 180 seconds.
- Game the system to get multiple periods of 180 seconds by influencing how you enter and exit regions with beacon placement.
- Live with the 10 second background ranging default.

Regardless of what option you choose, ranging for beacons is much, much more battery intensive than monitoring.  If you range constantly, expect to have a dead battery within a couple of hours.

Comment: Very good overview of the options. We will probably make a choice from these.

Comment: Do you know *why* ranging beacons uses so much power? I would have thought ranging still has to rely on receiving the data packets every x milliseconds from the beacon?  As it's receive only, it doesn't 'feel' like it should use much power.  I can't seem to find any details of what "ranging" actually is, or why the API can't tell indicate the range from the same packet it uses for monitoring/detection.   If anyone can provide any info on what actually happens for "ranging" I'd be very interested to know. CC: @RobertN

Comment: Ranging basically does a Bluetooth LE scan constantly and has the CPU process any packets it detects.

Answer (score 0):

The ranging on beacons is designed to be low power, but only used when in the foreground. When an app is closed or backgrounded it's only meant to handle the didEnterRegion and didExitRegion. Ranging itself isn't too power intensive, so I would say your culprit is locationManager.startUpdatingLocation. It will be firing up the GPS hardware and constantly getting your location, even though you're not using it.

Is your use case similar to that of the post you link to?

Comment: Our use case has things in common with the other post. In our case we want to track the location of the device while the user walks inside and outside several buildings. There are multiple overlapping regions, each region with multiple beacons. The users will only occasionally have the app in the foreground.

Comment: You can monitor not just for UDID but also major and minor changes. That way you will receive multiple didEnter and didExit notifications, enabling you see what building/room the user is in.

Comment: You are right. We will look into this as an alternative.