# Need help in integrating "iBeacon + BLE Peripheral Scanning iOS Background mode" feature

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon

There is one requirement in which I need to allow iOS App to communicate with the BLE Hardware when App is Killed by users or OS ( May or May not be forcefully).

This Hardware works as an iBeacon and BLE Peripheral simultaneously!

What we have done is:

- App Launch First Time --> Then Ask for AlwaysUsage Permission
- Start Scanning for iBeacon Region with UUID(uuidString: "{Provided UUID}") only (Minor value will be different)
- When `func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in the region: CLBeaconRegion)` callback is received, we are extracting Major & Minor value from the detected beacon, preparing a Service UUID string based on this value e.g.  if Major value is : 00 & Minor value is "11", concacting this will be "0011" and adding this final concated value as a prefix of device service UUID e.g. "0011-12345-12345-123452" to start scanning for BLE Peripheral.

So my BLECentralManager object would start scanning as

```
self?.bleCentralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: "0011-12345-12345-123452", options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: false])
```

Once the Peripheral is detected, rest of the BLE Operations are performed on this peripheral (i.e. Making Connection, Sending data to Specific Characteristic, and at last Drop the connection). This works good in foreground mode.

Now, I need to achieve the same mechanism in Background (i.e. App not running state). How can I achieve it?

NOTE:

- Monitoring for iBeacon region is never stopped. So I am able to awake my app even when it is not launched.
- But my query is, how can I start preparing the Major + Minor value string for the detected Beacon in background

Comment: You can't range beacons in the background but you can monitor for beacon region entry. When you enter the region you can start scanning for the BLE service. If the user terminates your app then you probably won't get any further region notifications.

Comment: Beacon Ranging won't work. That's true!
But I can get UserDidEnter/Exit the beacon range (For testing purpose I am sending local notification when user enters/exits the beacon range) if it is forcefully killed from "App Switcher > Swipe Up"!

Comment: Ok. That's all you need then.

Comment: @Paulw11 My query is How can I retrieve the Major & Minor Value when didEnterRegion callback is received. Right now I can see "nil" when printing the region's major/minor value in     

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) due to this, I am unable to define my DeviceService UUID to start scanning! Can you please tell me what am I missing?

Comment: Ok. I understand now. Yeah, you can't do it.  It would be much simpler if your BLE device just advertised a known service, that you can scan for, connect to and interrogate a characteristic to see if it is the peripheral you are interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS will launch your app upon beacon detection and you will get a `didEnter(region:)` callback.  At this time, you can immediately start beacon ranging with `locationManager.startRangingBeacons(...)` and you will get `didRangeBeacons(...)`callbacks for a few seconds -- long enough to read the major/minor identifiers and do the work you need.

Comment: Can you pls help?

I tried ranging for beacons in didEnter(region:) callback. It is not responding any callback in didRangeBeacons. 

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) { manager.startRangingBeacons(in: region as! CLBeaconRegion) sendLocalNotification(title: "didEnterRegion..", body: "Ranging Now") } 


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRange beacons: [CLBeacon], satisfying beaconConstraint: CLBeaconIdentityConstraint) { 

//Sending Local Notification here too. But not receiving any callback 
}

Comment: Make sure that (1) you have set the locationManager.delegate (2) Make sure the delegate method signature matches exactly (3) Make sure the region definition for when you start ranging matches the uuid of the beacon you are looking for.  (4) try getting ranging updates with the app in the foreground to verify you have it hooked up properly

Comment: I tried your suggested approach and getting the callback in background/killed state with didEnterRegion callback --> Then started Beacon Ranging --> Gettin callback in didRangeBeacons where I can identify Major & Minor value. I tried to extend this scanning with BackgroundTask but didRangeBeacon method is called for 30 to 40 seconds only instead of 3 mins. Can you pls help me?

I followed below link as you mentioned!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368403/beacon-ranging-in-background-on-ios

Comment: What you described is expected behavior in the latest iOS release.  Apple reduced the background time allowed from 180 seconds to 30 seconds.  To get longer time, you must declare location as one of the background modes in your Info.plist